# Calculate mean per group across all columns

Tags: r, mean

I have a dataframe (`df`) that looks like the following (with more columns and rows):

```
Cell_Cluster     ARB2     DRAB2A    FOXP2 ....
C18|O11.F2       2.234    0.315     3.325
C18|010.J2       0.215    1.215    -0.310
C18|S92.C1      -0.562    4.624     1.426
C20|O11.F2       1.150   -1.326     3.135
C20|S93.C2      -1.135    3.001    -2.932 
C21|010.J2       2.125    1.250     0.013
.
.
.
```

The columns after `Cell_Cluster` are all different genes. What I want to do is group by `Cell_Cluster` (everything before the "|" to be exact) and then within each of those groups, add a column representing the mean value per gene. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Clean up the grouping column then aggregate, e.g. `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(Cell_Cluster = sub('\\|.*', '', Cell_Cluster)) %>% summarise_all(mean)`

Comment: Where does the mean info actually go? My actual dataframe has over 4000 rows and over 7000 columns and I don't see a mean column or anything

Comment: You get out a new data frame that is all means which you can assign to a variable and manipulate further. Trying to insert means within the raw data is a bad idea, as differentiating raw data from summary statistics will be very hard (at least in wide form).

Answer (score 0):

We assume the input data frame is as shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

Now, assuming that you want the original data frame with an extra column, `mean` appended to it such that every row in a group has the same mean equal to the mean of all numeric columns in that group, since the mean of all those numbers equals the mean of the rowMeans in that group we can first take the rowMeans and then take the mean of those over the group.  For example, looking at rows 4 and 5

```
# mean of all elements in rows 4 and 5
mean(c(1.15, -1.326, 3.135, -1.135, 3.001, -2.932))
## [1] 0.3155

# take mean of row 4 and then mean of row 5 and then mean of those 2 means
mean(c(mean(c(1.15, -1.326, 3.135)), mean(c(-1.135, 3.001, -2.932))))
## [1] 0.3155
```

No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, mean = ave(rowMeans(DF[-1]), sub("\\|.*","",Cell_Cluster), FUN = mean))
```

giving:

```
  Cell_Cluster   ARB2 DRAB2A  FOXP2     mean
1   C18|O11.F2  2.234  0.315  3.325 1.386889
2   C18|010.J2  0.215  1.215 -0.310 1.386889
3   C18|S92.C1 -0.562  4.624  1.426 1.386889
4   C20|O11.F2  1.150 -1.326  3.135 0.315500
5   C20|S93.C2 -1.135  3.001 -2.932 0.315500
6   C21|010.J2  2.125  1.250  0.013 1.129333
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
Cell_Cluster     ARB2     DRAB2A    FOXP2
C18|O11.F2       2.234    0.315     3.325
C18|010.J2       0.215    1.215    -0.310
C18|S92.C1      -0.562    4.624     1.426
C20|O11.F2       1.150   -1.326     3.135
C20|S93.C2      -1.135    3.001    -2.932 
C21|010.J2       2.125    1.250     0.013"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to average every gene in the group, not single column, making *long format data* first might be helpful. You can use both `tidyr` and `data.table` packages.

### `tidyr` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
gene <-
  read_table("Cell_Cluster     ARB2     DRAB2A    FOXP2
C18|O11.F2       2.234    0.315     3.325
C18|010.J2       0.215    1.215    -0.310
C18|S92.C1      -0.562    4.624     1.426
C20|O11.F2       1.150   -1.326     3.135
C20|S93.C2      -1.135    3.001    -2.932 
C21|010.J2       2.125    1.250     0.013")
```

`gather(key, value)` can make the data long. You can specify column.

```
(gene1 <- 
  gene %>% 
  gather(-Cell_Cluster, key = key, value = value)) # gather except Cell_Cluster
#> # A tibble: 18 x 3
#>    Cell_Cluster key     value
#>    <chr>        <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 C18|O11.F2   ARB2    2.23 
#>  2 C18|010.J2   ARB2    0.215
#>  3 C18|S92.C1   ARB2   -0.562
#>  4 C20|O11.F2   ARB2    1.15 
#>  5 C20|S93.C2   ARB2   -1.14 
#>  6 C21|010.J2   ARB2    2.12 
#>  7 C18|O11.F2   DRAB2A  0.315
#>  8 C18|010.J2   DRAB2A  1.22 
#>  9 C18|S92.C1   DRAB2A  4.62 
#> 10 C20|O11.F2   DRAB2A -1.33 
#> 11 C20|S93.C2   DRAB2A  3.00 
#> 12 C21|010.J2   DRAB2A  1.25 
#> 13 C18|O11.F2   FOXP2   3.32 
#> 14 C18|010.J2   FOXP2  -0.31 
#> 15 C18|S92.C1   FOXP2   1.43 
#> 16 C20|O11.F2   FOXP2   3.14 
#> 17 C20|S93.C2   FOXP2  -2.93 
#> 18 C21|010.J2   FOXP2   0.013
```

Since you want to group by cell_cluster before `|` (if I understand right), you can separate the column into two. Split by `\\|`.

```
gene1 %>% 
  separate(Cell_Cluster, into = c("cell", "cluster"), 
           sep = "\\|", remove = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 5
#>    Cell_Cluster cell  cluster key     value
#>    <chr>        <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
#>  1 C18|O11.F2   C18   O11.F2  ARB2    2.23 
#>  2 C18|010.J2   C18   010.J2  ARB2    0.215
#>  3 C18|S92.C1   C18   S92.C1  ARB2   -0.562
#>  4 C20|O11.F2   C20   O11.F2  ARB2    1.15 
#>  5 C20|S93.C2   C20   S93.C2  ARB2   -1.14 
#>  6 C21|010.J2   C21   010.J2  ARB2    2.12 
#>  7 C18|O11.F2   C18   O11.F2  DRAB2A  0.315
#>  8 C18|010.J2   C18   010.J2  DRAB2A  1.22 
#>  9 C18|S92.C1   C18   S92.C1  DRAB2A  4.62 
#> 10 C20|O11.F2   C20   O11.F2  DRAB2A -1.33 
#> 11 C20|S93.C2   C20   S93.C2  DRAB2A  3.00 
#> 12 C21|010.J2   C21   010.J2  DRAB2A  1.25 
#> 13 C18|O11.F2   C18   O11.F2  FOXP2   3.32 
#> 14 C18|010.J2   C18   010.J2  FOXP2  -0.31 
#> 15 C18|S92.C1   C18   S92.C1  FOXP2   1.43 
#> 16 C20|O11.F2   C20   O11.F2  FOXP2   3.14 
#> 17 C20|S93.C2   C20   S93.C2  FOXP2  -2.93 
#> 18 C21|010.J2   C21   010.J2  FOXP2   0.013
```

Now you can calculate the mean for each group. You want additional column, so `dplyr::mutate()` can be used.

With `spread(key, value)`, you can go back to the original format.

```
gene %>% 
  gather(-Cell_Cluster, key = key, value = value) %>% 
  separate(Cell_Cluster, into = c("cell", "cluster"), 
           sep = "\\|", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(cell) %>% # group by cell column
  mutate(M = mean(value)) %>% # make mean column
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% # do not need cell and cluster column, so remove them
  select(-cell, -cluster)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Cell_Cluster     M   ARB2 DRAB2A  FOXP2
#>   <chr>        <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 C18|010.J2   1.39   0.215  1.22  -0.31 
#> 2 C18|O11.F2   1.39   2.23   0.315  3.32 
#> 3 C18|S92.C1   1.39  -0.562  4.62   1.43 
#> 4 C20|O11.F2   0.315  1.15  -1.33   3.14 
#> 5 C20|S93.C2   0.315 -1.14   3.00  -2.93 
#> 6 C21|010.J2   1.13   2.12   1.25   0.013
```

You can see the `M` column which has calculated each gene group.

### `data.table` approach

Gene data might be large, so `data.table` can be more appropriate to implement.

- Instead of `tidyr::gather()`, you can use `data.table::melt()`

  - `id.vars`
  - `variable.name`
- Instead of `tidyr::separate()`, you can use `data.table::tstrsplit()`

  - To use regular expression `\\|`, add `perl = TRUE`.
- Instead of `tidyr::spread()`, you can use `data.table::dcast()`

  - formula: In the left side, put id and adding variable. In the right side, put the original variable.
  - `value.var`

All at once,

```
gene %>% 
  data.table() %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Cell_Cluster", variable.name = "key") %>% # gather
  .[,
    c("cell", "cluster") := tstrsplit(Cell_Cluster, split = "\\|", perl = TRUE)] %>% # split Cell_Cluster
  .[,
    M := mean(value), # average value column
    by = cell] %>% # group by cell
  dcast(Cell_Cluster + M ~ key, value.var = "value") # spread

#>    Cell_Cluster     M   ARB2 DRAB2A  FOXP2
#> 1:   C18|010.J2 1.387  0.215  1.215 -0.310
#> 2:   C18|O11.F2 1.387  2.234  0.315  3.325
#> 3:   C18|S92.C1 1.387 -0.562  4.624  1.426
#> 4:   C20|O11.F2 0.315  1.150 -1.326  3.135
#> 5:   C20|S93.C2 0.315 -1.135  3.001 -2.932
#> 6:   C21|010.J2 1.129  2.125  1.250  0.013
```

This `data.table` would be much faster.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  DPLYR = {
    gene %>% 
  gather(-Cell_Cluster, key = key, value = value) %>% 
  separate(Cell_Cluster, into = c("cell", "cluster"), 
           sep = "\\|", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(cell) %>% 
  mutate(M = mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(key, value) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-cell, -cluster)
  },
  DATATABLE = {
    gene %>% 
  data.table() %>% 
  melt(id.vars = "Cell_Cluster", variable.name = "key") %>% 
  .[,
    c("cell", "cluster") := tstrsplit(Cell_Cluster, split = "\\|", perl = TRUE)] %>% 
  .[,
    M := mean(value),
    by = cell] %>%
  dcast(Cell_Cluster + M ~ key, value.var = "value")
  },
  times = 50
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>       expr  min    lq mean median    uq   max neval
#>      DPLYR 8.55 10.15 11.7  11.39 12.53 20.22    50
#>  DATATABLE 3.39  3.94  4.8   4.77  5.46  7.69    50
```